# CD extract isn't working in Rhythmbox

Tags: crash, music, rhythmbox, extract, lame

All my music is in the Rhythmbox music list and can be played normally. When I insert a new CD to an external USB drive I can play the CD, eject, etc. I click on "Extract" and the whole thing (Rhythmbox) shuts down. I have installed the restricted extras and I find no matching questions that have been answered concerning this problem. If you need more information you will need to tell me how to get it. I am good at command line and fairly comfortable using it. 
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
64-bit
Gnome version:3.36.8
This is a new installation, dual boot with windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed my problem:

```
    sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```